# accessible members in an angular factory or service

Tags: angularjs, factory

Is it recommended to have an accessible members array in a factory or service:

```
app.factory('myFactory', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    // accessible members
    var factory = {
        doSomething1: doSomething1,
        doSomething2: doSomething2
    };

    function doSomething1() {
        // do something
    };

    function doSomething2() {
        // do something
    };

    return factory;
};
```

versus the way I have been doing it:

```
app.factory('myFactory', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    factory.doSomething1 = function() {
        // do something
    };

    factory.doSomething2 = function() {
        // do something
    };

    return factory;
};
```

**Edit:** One thing I just learned is the second example, which is using a function expression for doSomething1 & 2 (function stored in a var), will not be hoisted to the top of the execution order. JavaScript will only hoist straight functions. So if I had my return statement before the function expressions, it would return undefined. In the first example, though, javascript will hoist the functions to the top, so it doesn't matter where I put the return. John Papa has a great explanation here:

[Angular Function Declarations, Function Expressions, and Readable Code](http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-function-declarations-function-expressions-and-readable-code/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version is better cause it's more readable.

Here you can find a very good style guide by John Papa: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Comment: HA! That is precisely what I am reading now and what prompted my question. I just wasn't sure if the having the accessible members in there was necessary. Now that I think about it, if you want to take advantage of hoisting, you have to use functions. If I use functions, they won't be accessible without declaring them as in the first example, right?